# My Error: unknown extension ?Pd at position 1

Tags: kaggle

I saw this error:

> unknown extension ?Pd at position 1

in

```
temp_nums = weather["temp"].str.extract("(?Pd+)", expand=False)
weather["temp_num"] = temp_nums.astype('int')
temp_nums
```

Answer (score 1):

Where it says `(?Pd+)`, type `(?P<temp_num>\d+)` instead like they did on this
[example](https://shaynemei.github.io/hackore/bs4_basic.html#Analysis).